# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'forEach') (using Parcel )

Tags: javascript, parceljs

```
['hashchange' &&'load'].forEach(ev => 
window.addEventListener(ev, controlRecipes))

// window.addEventListener('hashchange', controlRecipes)
// window.addEventListener('load', controlRecipes)
```

The following is the output from the CL

> controller.js:37 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'forEach')
> at Object.jKMjS../model.js (controller.js:37)
> at newRequire (index.436439df.js:71)
> at index.436439df.js:120
> at index.436439df.js:143

Comment: if it solves your issue mark it as answered

Answer (score 2):

remove `&&` and add `,` instead. `forEach` is used to go through an array. refer [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)